# Handle Push Notification in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, chat

i am using Kotlin Navigation component architecture for my chat app, and i am using Firebase Messaging service to integrate push notification, my requirement  is to hide or disable the notifications when i am on User chat screen.Please let me know, how can i achieve this.
this is my code of displaying notification

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
     
        Log.d(TAG, "From: ${remoteMessage?.from}")

        remoteMessage?.data?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "data payload: " + remoteMessage.data.toString())
            val params =remoteMessage.data.get("body")
            val objects = JSONObject(params)
            Log.e("JSON OBJECT", objects.toString())

            val title = remoteMessage.data.get("title").toString()

           sendNotification(messageBody,title, applicationContext)
} }
```

my notification class is:

```
fun NotificationManager.sendNotification(messageBody: String, title: String, applicationContext: Context) {

    notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

   
    // TODO: Step 1.12 create PendingIntent
    if(title.equals("Ride Request")) {
        fragmentId  = R.id.notificationFragment

    }
    else if(title.equals("Ride Accepted")) {
      fragmentId = R.id.inboxFragment
    }
    else if(title.equals("New Message")) {
        fragmentId = R.id.inboxFragment
    }

    // ---------- creating navgraph intent to open specific fragment ------------
    var contentPendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(applicationContext)
        .setComponentName(HomeActivity::class.java)
        .setGraph(R.navigation.home_bottom_navigation)
        .setDestination(fragmentId)
        .setArguments(bundle)
        .createPendingIntent()

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channel_id, description, 
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = R.color.colorPrimary
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

        builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_car)
            .setContentTitle(applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

    

    }else {

         builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, 
             applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_car)
            .setContentTitle(applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)


    }

    notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't if this is the perfect but you can try it as well

If the user is in chat screen you can create a sharedPref and set value of the variable to true (that the user is in chat screen)
So in the onMessageReceived() check it the value of the sharedPref is true (which mean the user is in chat screen)
If it's true then don't send notifications if false send notification

To set the sharedPref value
In the onResume of that chat activity set to true
In the onPause set to false

Comment: Thankyou so much, GeoDev_E, its a fine approach to hide the notification for cat window, i just needed to save one more parameter to sharedPref, that is chat_user_id, through which i am able to check if chat screen of particular user is open or closed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class InboxFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        var userId: String? = null
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        userId = navArgs.userId
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        userId = null
    }

}


class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        ...
        if (InboxFragment.userId != remoteMessage.data.get("userId"))
            sendNotification(messageBody, title, applicationContext)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou Sinner of the System, for your answer, its a right approach to achieve my requirement. But i needed to hide the notification only for a specific user chat which is open at now, but this method is hiding the notification for other users also, if my chat screen is open.

Comment: That is a different question. I change my answer